# How wireless charger automatic detect Rx Coil to turn on

Tags: wireless, charger

I want to know how wireless charger can detect 2nd coil then the switching at 1st coil is on, but when the 2nd coil isn't detected by 1st coil, the switching at 1st coil is turn off. How it happens? can someone explain it?

[image: red led means the switching at 1st coil is off, no Rx coil detected]

[image: Blue Led means 2nd coil is detected and switching at 1st coil is on]

and the ic [datasheet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiKxK6qlsCAAxWm2DgGHcDPBj0QFnoECA4QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdatasheet.lcsc.com%2Flcsc%2F2009281204_Shenzhen-Fuman-Elec-XPM7105A_C841232.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0KBcSpcM31iu2hclCvClkj&opi=89978449) is here.

Comment: typically, the MCU on the primary side would detect the current draw and then turn on the LEDs as an interface, but your datasheet is in Mandarin

Comment: Whisper - anybody there? No answer. Whisper - anybody there? No answer. Whisper - anybody there? Hi, there, I want some power! Shout - HAVE SOME POWER.

Comment: @Electrocol, Thanks for the answer, do you know the type of ic that is similar to with that IC (XPM7015)? I mean the IC type for the wireless charger?